# Xero - Category Options - via API

Tags: xero-api

I am happy to be corrected, but as I understand it there is a limit of a maximum of 100 category options per client that can be configured. Is this just a limitation set in Xero (within the browser) or can this be increased when accessing the client's Xero data via APIs?

Please advise.

Greg

I haven't tried it yet, and would seek the knowledge of others before trying it.

Answer (score 0):

Xero have just advised me that the 100 limit is in place to reduce load on their system, and that there are workarounds within Xero to achieve similar function.